# Unity style game engine for Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: pi-4, scratch

Is there any way to get a software sort of like [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)#Other_uses) for the raspberry pi 4? I want something sort of like it (with a graphics section) with real code, so not scratch. I do realize that the pi might not have enough CPU and GPU power to do it, but I'd at least like to try. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you looked at Processing? ... https://pi.processing.org/

Comment: why don't you search for alternates to unity for linux? ... see which ones run on limited hardware like the RPi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Godot](https://godotengine.org/) is a good game engine you can use on a Pi. It's pretty lightweight and there are a good amount of [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=godot) to help you get started. It's also completely free and [Open Source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot).

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely helpful.